# Windows CMD - Is there any way of getting the plain text from a compiled CHM help file and/or a PDF?

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf, grep, chm

I have a build chain based on Windows batch and Python files.  As part of the build, there are variables that are determined and are then communicated to the application CHM help compiler and PDF generator via a command line option which specifies a file containing the variable name-value pairs.

If a variable isn't defined the help compiler just leaves the meta-string in there, so instead of:

```
Build date: 15th December 2022
```

you get:

```
Build date: <%BUILD-DATE%>
```

I want to check the output CHM and PDF files for these unresolved references and flag the error.  I can do it easily with `grep`, but I need the files to be converted to plain text.  I tried `PDFtk` (PDF Toolkit) but it does weird things with the text, like adding a space character after every `W`!  I guess this is because it works by rendering the PDF as an image and OCR'ing the result.

I don't know what I can try for the CHM file (I believe these are in fact archives).

Any ideas?

Comment: you may decompile the CHM file [(scroll down on this site, see method 5)](https://www.help-info.de/kb/en/HTMLHelp/100007-hh-decompile-chm.html) resulting in HTML files and use Notepad++ combined with RegEx to search in these files.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  I have written a batch file that extracts all the HTM files and concatenates them into one big HTM file.  Now to think about a way of stripping all the HTML tags, but as you point out, `grep` should be able to be used to essentially ignore the markup.

Comment: Starting point for parsing the HTML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67792/using-powershell-to-parse-local-html-document-then.html but use the hh.exe to decompile, then check html folder of extracted HTML files that make up the content. Parse those accordingly for needed tag values per the link I provided. [Edit] when you get to it to provide example HTML or code you are having trouble getting to work.